# How to know if a bastion or vpn is the right solution?

Tags: ssh, vpn, bastion

How do you choose between using a bastion or VPN when providing access to a vlan?  I have seen many different setups, but don't have a good idea on how to make a less subjective selection.  Is there a known list to help select?  I know there are many factors including price, vendor, technical experience, preference, etc., that aside, I hope there is a more standard way to pick.

Comment: I suspect this is going to be closed as "primarily opinion based", because it really is a subjective question that involves a number of non-technical issues like your budget and the technical ability of people who will need to use the solution. You may have applications that simply won't work with a bastion host solution.